# strip off prefix of URL's

Tags: c#, uri

I have got the following log of URL strings. The logs contain millions of records.

```
www.example.com/p1?q=k
example.com/p1?q=k
http://example.com/p1?q=k
https://example.com/p1?q=k
http://www.example.com/p1?q=k
```

I used the C# Uri class but it throws an excepition for format of type "example.com/p1?q=K"
I was wondering if there is a generally/standard accepted method for dealing with such different types of URL to get websitename & the relative URL.

P.S: I could strip off http:// & https:// by using a regex or string comparision, but curious to know if there are any elegant solutions

Comment: `if there is a generally/standard accepted method` Yes it is `Uri` :)

Comment: Yeah, but it throws an exception for log of type
"example.com/p1?q=k"

Comment: Append http://, https:// or www. to it if doesn't exist, in case it happens during the construction of an Uri instance

Comment: what you have is not a valid uri, if you want to do what you are doing you will need to have `http://www.` in the `uri` then you could replace the code removing the `www` storing it as a variable then appending it I will paste some code for you to get started and playing around with..

Comment: @MethodMan according to corresponding RFC Uri does not have to be absolute all the time... OP showed several samples of relative uri (i.e  no schema part) which hadled perfectly fine by .Net `Uri` class when explcitly specifying "relative" as type... Not sure why you thing they are "not valid".

Answer (score 1):

If you try it with your existing example it will not work.. however you can play around with this and do some appending code where needed which means you will need to create a few variables to store the `http://, https://, and www.`

```
System.Uri uriPre = new Uri ("http://www.example.com/p1?q=k"); 
string uriString = uriPre.Host + uriPre.PathAndQuery;
uriString = uriString.Replace("www.", "");
```

yields

```
"example.com/p1?q=k"
```

- the rest of the coding you will have to figure out because only you would know when to utilize the different protocols base on the example I've provided

to expand on `Alexei Levenkov` answer here is an example that you can use to try to create a new Uri.

```
Uri tempValue;
var uriPre = new Uri(string.Empty, UriKind.Relative);
if (Uri.TryCreate("example.com/p1?q=k", UriKind.Relative, out tempValue))
{
    // do something or retrun tempValue;
}
```

Comment: I assume you know that `= new Uri(string.Empty, UriKind.Relative);` is completely useless due to `out`...

Comment: yes I do know that I was just showing an example because I do not know what the `OP` was intending to do in the conditional check .. I was actually going to post that `var uriPre = new Uri(string.Empty, UriKind.Relative);` is unnecessary that I was just using as an example to show that `tempValue` was being returned properly

Answer (score 0):

`Uri` it the class that is designed to deal with Uris

```
var noSchemaRelativeUri = new Uri("example.com/foo", UriKind.Relative);
```

Either `UriBuilder` or `Uri(Uri base, Uri relative)` can be used to construct absolute Uri.

To pick between relative and aboslute you can use [`Uri.TryCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Note. "www.example.com" and "example.com" strictly speaking are unrelated domain names, converting one to another is not guaranteed to always produce registered domain name (also indeed most sites register both and do some sort of redirect between).

Comment: I updated my answer to provide the `OP` with an example based on your recommendation of using the `Uri.TryCreate`